# Selectfield in sencha touch doesn't respect an empty value

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've noticed a problem with ST2 and selectfield pickers.  I'm testing this on Desktop browser and tablet and both seem to show the same problem.

The problem seems to stem from having form data that is empty or uninitialised.
My example is a user logs into their account and needs to set their marital status. As this has never been set before the backing store model is actually 'null' for their marital status. When they click the picker, the pick for some reason picks the first item in the checklist automatically. This is evident by the check-mark on the right side of the item.  The 2nd side-effect of this is, if you then select the first item, ST2 doesn't see this as an item change and so doesn't then propagate the selection change back to the form.

Is this is a bug? How do I get round this problem?

```
Ext.define('Gender', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'ItemName',  type: 'string'}           
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('Details', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [       
            {name: 'Gender',  type: 'int'}           
        ]
    }
});

var myGenderStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Gender',
    data : [
        {Id: 1, ItemName: 'Male'},
        {Id: 2, ItemName: 'Female'}
    ]   
});

var myDetailsStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Details',
    data : [
        { Gender: null }        
    ]   
});

var p = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Select',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    displayField: 'ItemName',
                    valueField: 'Id',
                    store: myGenderStore,
                    name: 'Gender'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

p.setRecord(myDetailsStore.getAt(0))
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(p);
// notice the picker has 'Male' selected even though the backing store for the Gender field is null
// also, we want to select Male from the list, but this isn't reflected on the form
// run below command in console window after selecting 'Male' even though it is selected and it shows null
// It only seems to like changes to the value as selecting female works. If then select Male from Female this also works.
p.getValues().Gender;
```

Comment: please post your code for better understanding of your question

Comment: Hi sai, I've added a code sample which shows the problem. Not sure if I'm missing something really obvious here?!?

Answer (score 0):

you can set value for the select field

```
 p.down('selectfield[name=Gender]').setValue(myGenderStore.getAt(0).get('Id'))
```

see example: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#OuCtQ#GQJ2C

thanks

Comment: When I run this, the selected field on the form is 'Male'. Shouldn't it not be set to anything?

Comment: try this [http://www.senchafiddle.com/#OuCtQ#GQJ2C#yP7aw](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#OuCtQ#GQJ2C#yP7aw)

Comment: if yuo don't want **Select gender** try this link [http://www.senchafiddle.com/#OuCtQ#GQJ2C#yP7aw#QFiTJ](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#OuCtQ#GQJ2C#yP7aw#QFiTJ)

Comment: Thanks for this, I was kind of looking for the select list to only have the options that I want selected without an 'empty' option and have no option with a tick mark against it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the **autoSelect** config property to **false**,to prevent default selection like this:

```
 {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Choose one',
                    displayField: 'ItemName',
                    valueField: 'Id',
                    store: myGenderStore,
                    name: 'Gender',
                    autoSelect:false
                }
```